# Custom transition on UINavigationController back swipe

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, uinavigationcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UINavigationController` with custom transitions when pushing and popping using the `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` protocol:

```
class NavigationHandler: UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationController.Operation, from fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return CustomAnimator()
    }
}

class CustomAnimator: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {
    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        // do animation stuff
    }
}
```

This works fine for push and pop, but it doesn't work for the back-swipe gesture (which will show the default transition). I would like to customize the back swipe, but can't find a good way to do that.

Knowledge I gained so far:

- Setting up my own gesture recognizer to detect the back swipe is possible, but `UINavigationController` will still perform the default animation, so now my animation fights the default animation, which seems wrong
- `UINavigationControllerDelegate` has a method `navigationController(:interactionControllerFor animationController:)`, which seems like it's exactly what I need, but it's only called for regular push/pop operations, not for back swipe